# Network with 2 routers and Raspberrys

Tags: router, home-networking, raspberry-pi

I have the following network at home:

[image]

I want to create a local network setup for my Raspis and the LinkSys router, so that I can move them around at work or home for easy configuration. I will just plug in an ethernet cable to the WAN IP interface of the linksys and my local raspi network will remain the same. The linksys router is configured as an access point and operates in an automatic DHCP mode. FritzBox is also auto DHCP. So, in my example at home:

What works:

1. The Raspis have Internet connection
2. The Rapsis can ping all devices in the network
3. The Raspis can open ssh connections to my laptop and between each other

What doesn't work:

1. The laptop does not ping the WAN IP that the LinkSys router receives, although they are on the same network (there is an option in the dd-wrt control panel for the LinkSys to allow anonymous pings. If I enable this ping succeeds). But the main issue remains:
2. The laptop does not ping the Raspis / or ssh them

I have limited networking knowledge. Could you point as to what is missing from my configuration to enable access from my laptop to the local raspi network?

Answer (score 0):

> The laptop does not ping the Raspis / or ssh them

Neither your laptop nor your main router know where the second network *is*. At least one of them needs a static route to be added for 192.168.110.0/24 via 192.168.179.46.

(Currently outgoing connections still work because the DD-WRT performs NAT, hiding its inner addresses from the outer networ.)

The DD-WRT firewall also needs to *allow* packets coming in from what it considers to be "WAN".

Comment: Thanks. I added the route you suggested in my laptop and now I can ping 192.168.110.1, i.e., the second router's local ip. But I can't go one step deeper to ping the devices. Any suggestions?

Comment: adding an update. I disabled the SPI firewall in the second router and now I have full access to the secondary network. But I suppose this is not the way to go, so a more elegant solution would be nice