# How to configure Modem and Router allows devices ping from different subnets in a mesh network setup?

Tags: linux, networking, ping, subnet, mesh-networking

I'm having trouble with my network and need some help.

I have a modem and three home gateway routers set up as a mesh network, with one acting as the controller and the other two as agents. My modem router has an IP gateway of 192.168.1.1, and my controller router is connected to the modem via a WAN link. The two agents are connected to the controller router via Wi-Fi, and their gateway IPs are 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.2.253.

I have a laptop1 that's connected to my modem's Wi-Fi with the IP 192.168.1.3, and another laptop2 that's connected to the home gateway's Wi-Fi with the IP 192.168.2.9. I can ping from laptop2 to laptop1, but the reverse is not working.

Could you please help me configure my modem or router so that laptop1 and laptop2 can communicate with each other? Thank you!

Sample:[image]

Comment: Why don't you just flatten the network so the "home gateway routers" are acting as a mesh network?   Also, unless you advise the make (and maybe model) of your gear I don't think anyone can help you.

Comment: This sounds like a very common situation that has been discussed here many times; e.g. https://superuser.com/a/1372634/1686 (with a decent explanation) and https://superuser.com/a/1661706/1686 and https://superuser.com/a/1736107/1686 and https://superuser.com/a/1464915/1686 just from my own list...

Comment: Just to be sure, though: since you're saying the modem router has a different subnet from the rest (i.e. it's not quite "mesh network", it's just a network), does it also have a different Wi-Fi SSID from the rest? For access points leading to different subnets, the SSIDs need to be different as well.

Comment: Thank user1686!
 My problems solved by setting Static Routing in the modem, make it point to my router.